# Read first and last value from a column in a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a way to find the values of a specific column in a dataframe with multiindexing.

It looks similiar to this;

```
                                           A  ...            Id
UniqueKey                                     ...              
ffffffffffff_20190603-104838.json 0      NaN  ...  ffffffffffff
                                  1      NaN  ...  ffffffffffff
                                  2      NaN  ...  ffffffffffff
                                  3      NaN  ...  ffffffffffff
                                  4      NaN  ...  ffffffffffff
```

In this dataframe I have a column with a unix time, which I will convert to a string, so I imagined that I could write something like this:

Where, name is equal to one of the UniqueKeys, in the dataframe

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values('UniqueKey') == name].at[0, 'epochTime'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I want for each UniqueKey in the dataframe to get the first and last value of the column 'epochTime'

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```
df.groupby('UniqueKey')['epochTime'].agg({'first', 'last'})
```